# clearing the textbox input on button click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i do have multiple text boxes called first name,last name,phone no and so on.. and i want to clear/refresh the input typed in it on button click called as refresh or clear.the problem is that the input in these text boxes are not getting refreshed because the data in it is coming from other page and it is getting refreshed when we type some thing in it
my code is as follows:

```
<div class="control-group">
        <input value="<?php echo $model['pros']['oppid'] ?>" name="oppid" type="hidden" id="prospectid"  />
        <label class="control-label">First Name  </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="f_name" pattern="[-a-zA-Z]+" required="" title="First Name is required" value="<?php echo $model['pros']["f_name"]; ?>"  />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Last Name </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="l_name" pattern="[-a-zA-Z]+" required="" title="Last Name is required"  value="<?php echo $model['pros']["l_name"];?>"  />
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Primary phone  </label>
        <div class="controls">
<input type="tel" required="" pattern="[-0-9]+" title="Please Enter correct phone" name="pri_phone" value="<?php echo $model['pros']["pri_phone"];?>"  />
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the button as

```
<button class="btn">New</button>
```

please suggest me on this...

Comment: Do you want to clear the value for them all? Or just one of them?

Comment: you can use jquery or javascript to clear data from the fields using `onclick` method

Comment: please give the code..and i want to clear all of them

Comment: the reset input would not clear the inputs, it would reset them to the php default values

Comment: ya i got the solution but now i have to clear all the form which are containing table and drop down as well

Comment: `$('button.btn').click(function(e){ $('#formid').reset(); });` if you are using `<form>` tag, where `formid` is the attribute id you have given to your form tag

Comment: yes sure!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following code:

```
$("#elementid").live('click',function(){
     $(this).parents('form').find('input[type="text"]').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `input` elements are inside of a form, and so too is your button, you can do this using jQuery:

```
$('button.btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    $(this).parents('form').find('input[type="text"], input[type="tel"]').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can write code in jquery as:

```
$('#new').live('click',function(){
   $('#fname').val('');
   $('#lname').val('');
   $('#tel').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your button is *not* within the form you can use the following

```
$('button.btn').click(function() {
   $('.control-group input:not(:submit)').val('');
});
```

This will reset any type of input within the `control-group` divs except for submit inputs

If your reset button *is* within the form then [BenM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13643762/871150)'s answer is what you want.

Comment: Including buttons, and the form will be submitted when the button is clicked.

Comment: the form would only get submitted if the buttons markup was like so: `<button type="submit">New</button>`, but yes this would also empty an `<input type="submit" value="submit" />` buttons value

Comment: Not true. See this jsFiddle demo > http://jsfiddle.net/RqsEz/. The button has no type, but still submits the form...

Comment: touché. I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".clearform").live('click',function(){
     $(this).parents('form').find('input[type="text"], input[type="tel"],input[type="time"],input[type="email"],input[type="number"],input[type="date"],select').val('');
});
```

Comment: you can write code in jquery as:

$('#new').live('click',function(){
   $('#fname').val('');
   $('#lname').val('');
   $('#tel').val('');
});